# Getting "AssertionError: No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer." when trying to finetune Mistral LLM - How to fix?

Tags: python, large-language-model, fine-tuning

I encountered an AssertionError with the message "No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer" when using PyTorch's Automatic Mixed Precision (AMP) module during training. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

```
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset, Dataset
from peft import LoraConfig, AutoPeftModelForCausalLM, prepare_model_for_kbit_training, get_peft_model
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, GPTQConfig, TrainingArguments, Trainer
from trl import SFTTrainer
import os
import pandas as pd
import transformers
def finetune_mistral_7b():
    data_df = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")

    # Assuming your CSV has "category" and "description" columns
    # Combine "category" and "description" columns into a new "text" column
    data_df["text"] = data_df[["Category", "Description"]].apply(
        lambda x: "<human>: What description does the category" + x["Category"] + "have?" + "\n<assistant>" + x["Description"],
        axis=1
    )
    # Convert the DataFrame into a Hugging Face dataset
    data = Dataset.from_pandas(data_df)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1-GPTQ")
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    tokenizer.padding_side = 'right'
    quantization_config_loading = GPTQConfig(bits=4, disable_exllama=True, tokenizer=tokenizer)
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
                              "TheBloke/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.1-GPTQ",
                              quantization_config=quantization_config_loading,
                              device_map="auto"
                        )
    print(model)
    model.config.use_cache=False
    model.config.pretraining_tp=1
    model.gradient_checkpointing_enable()
    model = prepare_model_for_kbit_training(model)
    
    peft_config = LoraConfig(
        r=16, lora_alpha=16, lora_dropout=0.05, bias="none", task_type="CAUSAL_LM", target_modules=["q_proj", "v_proj"]
    )
    peft_config.inference_mode = False
    
    model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
    training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir="mistral-finetuned-samsum",
        per_device_train_batch_size=8,
        gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
        optim="paged_adamw_32bit",
        learning_rate=2e-4,
        lr_scheduler_type="cosine",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        logging_steps=100,
        num_train_epochs=1,
        max_steps=250,
        fp16=True,
        push_to_hub=True
    )
    trainer = SFTTrainer(
        model=model,
        train_dataset=data,
        peft_config=peft_config,
        dataset_text_field="text",
        args=training_arguments,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        packing=False,
        max_seq_length=512
    )
    trainer.train()
    trainer.push_to_hub()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    finetune_mistral_7b()
```

Then I get the following error when I run the script

```
--> 372 assert len(optimizer_state["found_inf_per_device"]) > 0, "No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer."
    374 retval = self._maybe_opt_step(optimizer, optimizer_state, *args, **kwargs)
    376 optimizer_state["stage"] = OptState.STEPPED

AssertionError: No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer.
```

I tried adding the disabling inference mode by calling

```
peft_config.inference_mode = False
```

Which allowed my script to run up to 13 steps out of 250. But everytime at the 13th step the error occurs. Could be due to peft version? It seems to only happen with my own data, whether it be from HuggingFace or csv file.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is you dataset size. the error is saying "No inf checks were recorded for this optimizer" means that the optimizer did not find any infinite gradients during training. This could be due to dataset size, learning rate or the training algorithm. But I would suggest to increase you dataset size and see if you issue is solved before checking for the other issues. When I'm saying to increase dataset : for instance if your dataset is of 1000 rows, duplicate rows to reach 5000 rows and test if the error is solved.